# Python: use list from file in subfolder in main script

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I currently have lists in three different files each in their own subdirectory. I am looking to plot these (together with some other stuff) using a script in the main directory. How do I best/simplest go around doing this?

I have tried playing around with different import and with open options but haven't gotten any to work (may well be due to me making mistakes). I also considered writing out the individual lists to new files in my subdirectories and then just calling these but again I got stuck even just trying to write out the list.

I've now done a decent bit of looking around and not yet managed to make something work so any methods, good links or general advice would be very greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Can you share your folder structure (or a MRE of it) and the code you've been using to try to import them in the main script?

Comment: Check [ask] and [mre] please

Answer (score 1):

Create **init**.py file in each subfolder
And write in your main file :

```
from <<parentfolder.name_of_your_folder>> import <<name_of_the_file_which_contain_lists>> [as <<alias_name>>]
```

Use the file imported in the main file :

```
print(<name_of_the_file_which_contain_lists>.<name_of_variable_which_contain_lists>)
```